# How to match this strange null value

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, null, amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I encountered a very strange character that will not be displayed in my redshift table [image: img1], but when I upload the data to tableau as a csv file, an error will be reported [image: img 2]

I opened this file and found that it was caused by this red null character. [image: img 3]，and I can only see it when I open it with vscode, but I can't see it with the text tool that comes with mac.

this line data: `2023-11-27,1yrphmgdpgulaszriylqiipemefmacafkxycjaxjs.jpg,Chinese,Houston,,,,Other,Other,1,0,0.00000000000000000,0,1,0,0.00000000000000000,0,,,1,1,`

What is this character and how can I match and filter out data containing this character via redshift sql？

Comment: From site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 0):

That non-printing character appears to be ASCII(0), so I suggest trying the following:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, CHAR(0), '')
```

As you chose to supply your query as an image, I haven't attempted to use the actual column or table names, I leave that for you to perform.